# How to find the maxima/minima of a function using a software?

Tags: optimization, math-software

I want to find the maxima/minima of a function in an interval. Is there any software or online tool available for this?

The particualr function I want to maximize is,
$$f(x) = x(1 - \sqrt{2e} \cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-x}), 0 < x< \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha should be able to handle that

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram|Alpha gives you a numerical solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+x%281-%282ex%29%5E%281%2F2%29e%5E%28-x%29%29%2C+0%3Cx%3C1%2F2

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron. That did the job!